# Change Keyboard Shortcuts for Codeblocks on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: shortcut-keys, code-blocks

On Windows, the Codeblocks keyboard shortcuts can be changed using a plugin. My guess is this plugin modifies a script or config file to store the modifications and assignments.

I am guessing the Linux version of codeblocks also has such a configuration file, even if there is no plugin to change the shortcuts using the gui.

If there is such a file, where is it? And if there isn't such a file, or it cannot be "easily" modified by a human, then is it possible to change the keyboard shortcuts on for Code::Blocks on Linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has taken me many years to answer this question.

http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=9091.0

`sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib`